# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber, typeerror, undefined

After some tests in protractor - typescript - cucumber framework, I use this function:

```
Before({ tags: "@Cleanup" }, async function () {
    const JSESSION = await browser.manage().getCookie('JSESSIONID');
    const value = JSESSION.value;

    console.log('JSESSIONID = ', value);

    let request = require('request');

    let headers = {
        'accept': '*/*',
        'COOKIE': 'JSESSIONID='+value
    };

    let options = {
        url: 'http://someurl.com/cleanup/12647',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers
    };

    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Status code is: ', response.statusCode);
        }
    }
    
    request(options, callback); 
})
```

And I am getting this error:

```
E/launcher - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode')
```

This is happening since I've done some updates (nodeJS, npm, cucumber). Before it worked perfectly.

Any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you loop through multiple request on server, there are chances that socket may get hanged up (busy on some other request) or server can't queue the request which can result into no response from request. Best solution to this is, you must check response object from request first before accessing properties on it.

check this:  [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusCode') Nodejs using cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70818326/cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-statuscode-nodejs-using-cheerio)